# getting the sum of all sub-strings of a numeric string input

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

I was struggling with an online programming contest which had asked me to **get the sum of all sub-strings of a numeric string  input**, when I encountered a memory related exception.

For instance, for the input of "123" the desired output is "164".
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sam-and-substrings/problem

The problem seemed easy and I came up with a dynamic-programming solution. 
What I did was a bottom-up approach which got all sub-strings and added them together.

I think the solution itself was correct, because it passed more than 50% of the test-cases. Here is my simple solution:

```
static int substrings(string n)
        {
            decimal totalSubstring = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 1; j <= n.Length - i; j++)
                {
                    var strNumber = n.Substring(i, j);
                    decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(strNumber);
                    totalSubstring = totalSubstring + (number);
                }
            }
            return (int)(totalSubstring % 1000000007);
        }
```

However, when it received a long string (for example a string with more than **6426** characters), no primitive type could hold the long converted sub-string.

I know the error completely sounds logical, though I have no idea how to handle long strings.

Please **NOTE** that I am not looking for the exact answer, and I want to solve the problem myself. I would be glad, if someone could give me a hint or tell me if this solution can be fixed.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `decimal`.

Comment: There must be a much easier solution. I heard that, developers who use C programming language have tailored a solution for the similar problems! Do you have any idea?

Comment: I doubt there's going to be an easier solution that handles numbers with > 6K digits!

Comment: @MatthewWatson the problem request is to return it modulo 10^9 + 7

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that you'd like to solve the problem yourself, here's one other way to think about it. In the example, "123", the digit, 1, appears as

```
1
10
100
```

the digit, 2, appears as

```
2
2
20
20
```

and the digit, 3, appears as

```
3
3
3
```

1 + 10 + 100 + 2 + 2 + 20 + 20 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 164

Comment: @Erno um 123 and 23 both have 2 as 20?